# Python .exe for XP

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, exe, windows-xp

I am having some problems when I try to build a .exe app for windows XP.

I have tried several different "solutions" for this problem.

The OS I am using is windows 11.

First I created a virtual env with anaconda and installed python 3.4.3. Then I compiled a simple program using py2exe. The error I got is a missing "ddl", namely msvcr100.dll. I could not find a solution for this problem, since the visual studio versions I have installed are newer.
Another problem with this approach is that I am not able to install packages which are used in the script, for example opencv and numpy.

Next I installed python 3.7.9 32 bit. The error I got there is:

```
The procedure entry point GetFinalPathNameByHandleW could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll
```

Does someone know which of those two different approach will be better to continue to try? And does someone have a solution for the missing dll's?

Comment: 1. The best approach would be to stop using Windows XP as it is EOL and no longer receives security updates (I believe the last one was in April 19). 2. The next best approach will be to build the exe on a Windows XP machine with the same architecture as the target machine.

Comment: Are you getting the error when launching on windows xp ? Or when trying to compile into an exe? Also im pretty sure windows 11 is 64 bit....and big problems unrelated to python happen when building on 64 to run on 32....

Comment: Stick with Python 3.4 for that, 3.7 will not work.

Comment: Also note 3.7.9 cannot be used on widows XP, as noted [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). As for the DLL problem - check https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5 Also, I would suggest using pyinstaller, instead of py2exe. But the best, as advised by @DeepSpace - upgrade target OS.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I got the error on the XP machine, the program itself compiled fine. And yes if it was up to me we would not use windows (xp) but unfortunately it is not up to me.. ;)

Comment: I am not able to install pyinstaller (which I used normally for these kind of tasks), therefore I switched to py2exe. The tutorial states that we can use microsoft c++ 2008, but I am not able to find a installer and use it on my machine. I have visual studio in Program files (x86) and only dll's with *140.dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Python 3.5.0 Windows XP is no longer supported and you will see a bold

> **Note that Python 3.5.0 cannot be used on Windows XP or earlier.**

notice on the [Python Releases for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) page

The latest supported version is 3.4.3

See also: https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/windows.html#supported-versions

> As specified in PEP 11, a Python release only supports a Windows platform while Microsoft considers the platform under extended support. This means that Python 3.7 supports Windows Vista and newer. If you require Windows XP support then please install Python 3.4.